# Get the unavailable status of an xmpp contact

Tags: c#, xmpp

I am making a windows chat client using Jabber-Net Library.
When the User exits, I use this code to set the Unavailable status... so that people can see their offline status. Its visible in XMPP clients like Spark. But I cannot get the status of the other contact. setting this status.... 
How can I get it. Please Help!!...

```
     jabberClient1.Presence(jabber.protocol.client.PresenceType.unavailable, ApplicationVariables.chatstatus, ApplicationVariables.chatpresence, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it myself... and I am happy to share it. Let it be useful to people who wants this..

```
public void RequestLastMessage(JID jabberid)
{
    try
    {
        LastIQ iq = new LastIQ(jabberClient1.Document);
        iq.To = jabberid;

        iq.Type = jabber.protocol.client.IQType.get;
        jabberClient1.Tracker.BeginIQ(iq, LastMessage, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DebugLogger.LogRecord(ex.Message + " [ Function: " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " Class: XMPPWrapper ]");
    }
}

private void LastMessage(object sender, jabber.protocol.client.IQ iq, object state)
{
    try
    {
        if ((iq == null) || (iq.Type != jabber.protocol.client.IQType.result))
            return;
        Last ll = iq.Query as Last;
        if (iq.From != null && ll.Message != "")
            if (ApplicationVariables.GlobalContactForm != null) ApplicationVariables.GlobalContactForm.SetOfflineStatus(ll.Message, iq.From);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DebugLogger.LogRecord(ex.Message + " [ Function: " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " Class: XMPPWrapper ]");
    }

}
```